# Excel VBA For next and if then delete row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code that if there is an IR clinic completed but all Biopsy entries are canceled for the same ID, then I want to delete the row where the IR is. Row 1 is headers. Column B is IDs, column L is either "Biopsy" or "IR clinic". Column C is either "Completed" or "Canceled"

```
For i = 2 To LastRow
    If Range("L" & i).Value = "IR Clinic" And Range("C" & i).Value = "Completed" Then
        For j = 2 To i
            If  Range("B" & j).Value = Range("B" & i).Value And _
                Range("L" & j).Value = "Biopsy" And _
                Range("C" & j).Value = "Canceled" Then

                    Selection.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
                    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
                    i = i - 1
                    Exit For

            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next i
```

The problem with this code is if there is at least one Biopsy Canceled, it deletes the IR row. What I really need is if ALL biopsy for same ID are canceled it deletes it, but if at least one is completed, it does not delete the IR.
Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65751206/8422953

Comment: @braX: I don't think that this is the case since `i = i - 1` is covering it.

Comment: post sample dataset also

Answer (score 1):

### The Shortcomings of (Simplifications in) a `For...Next Loop`

**The Code**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    i = 2
    Do
    'For i = 2 To LastRow ' LastRow is stored; you cannot effectively modify it
        If Range("L" & i).Value = "IR Clinic" _
                And Range("C" & i).Value = "Completed" Then
            For j = 2 To i
                ' Note the change in this logic!
                If Range("B" & j).Value = Range("B" & i).Value _
                        And Range("L" & j).Value = "Biopsy" _
                        And Range("C" & j).Value <> "Canceled" Then ' or '= "Completed"'
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
            If j > i Then ' if the loop was uninterrupted; all canceled; none completed
                Rows(i).Delete
                LastRow = LastRow - 1
                i = i - 1
            'Else ' the loop was interrupted; not all canceled; at least one was completed
            End If
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop Until i > LastRow
End Sub
```

**The Outer Loop**

- This illustrates why the line `LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row` in your code is redundant (you might have used `LastRow = LastRow - 1` to the same effect).
- Whatever you do to `fr` or `lr`, it will only loop 5 times. Before entering the loop, VBA has stored the numbers `fr` and `lr` somewhere.

```vb
Sub ForNext1()
    Dim fr As Long: fr = 2 ' irrelevant
    Dim lr As Long: lr = 6
    Dim i As Long
    For i = fr To lr
        ' do your stuff
        fr = 2 * i ' irrelevant
        lr = 3 * i
        Debug.Print "i = " & i, "fr = " & fr, "lr = " & lr
    Next i
End Sub
```

- Mimic the behavior of `ForNext1` by using a `Do...Loop`.

```vb
Sub DoLoop()
    Dim fr As Long: fr = 2 ' irrelevant
    Dim lr As Long: lr = 6
    Dim i As Long: i = fr
    Do
        ' do your stuff
        fr = 2 * i ' irrelevant
        lr = 3 * i
        Debug.Print "i = " & i, "fr = " & fr, "lr = " & lr
        ' Next
        i = i + 1
        lr = 6 ' Gotcha! Here we can effectively change 'lr'!!!
    Loop Until i > lr
End Sub
```

**The Inner Loop**

- This relates to the utilization of the line `If j > i Then` in the code.
- When exiting uninterrupted, `j` is equal to `i + 1` (`6`), not `i` (`5`).

```vb
Sub ForNextTEST2()
    Dim i As Long: i = 5
    Dim j As Long
    For j = 1 To i
    Next j
    Debug.Print "j = " & j, "i = " & i
End Sub
```